# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 2d array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm probably missing something really obvious but can any of you guys see why this produces a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
I'm trying to create a 2d list of Visables objects the 2d list must only have the one column though.

```
public Visables[][] searchBYsong(String search) throws XPathExpressionException

{

   MapVariableResolver vr = new MapVariableResolver() ;
   vr.setVariable("myVar",search);
   xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(vr);

   XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/music/Song[contains(songName,$myVar)]");
   nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);


   Visables[][] AL = new Visables[nodes.getLength()+1][0];
   for(int i = 0;i<nodes.getLength();i++)
   {
       AL[i][0]= new Visables();

   }
   for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
   {


       AL[i][0].getName(nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
       AL[i][0].setArtist(nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
       AL[i][0].setAlbum(nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent());
       AL[i][0].setLocation(nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent());
   }


   return AL;
}

  public class Visables 
{

private String loaction;

private String name;

private String album;

private String artist;

public  Visables()
{

}


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return name;
}
public void setArtist(String artist)
{
  this.artist=artist;   
}
public void getName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
public void setAlbum(String album)
{
    this.album = album;
}
public void setLocation(String location)
{

 this.loaction=location;   
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `[0]` in this statement

```
Visables[][] AL = new Visables[nodes.getLength()+1][0];
```

means that you create an array with `zero` elements. Once you access the `first` element:

```
AL[i][0]= new Visables();
```

You get this error. In the previous statement `[0]` means the first element.

To solve this you need to create an array with 1 element. So create your array like this:

```
Visables[][] AL = new Visables[nodes.getLength()+1][1];
```

And access like this (unchanged):

```
AL[i][0]= new Visables();
```

I can see how this might be a bit confusing :)